# adding an arraylist to an arraylist, error required variable found value java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void insertData(int row, int col, String data){
    ArrayList<String> rowArray = this.data.remove(row);
    rowArray.remove(col);
    rowArray.add(col, data);
    this.data.add(row,rowArray) = data;
}
```

i am making a method for changing the data in a 2 dimensional array list, made from an array list of an array list of strings. to change the data i am removing the first row then changing the appropriate element in the row, then returning the row to its original position but when i try to in the last line i get un expected type required variable found value

Comment: You can't assign something to the return value of a method (`this.data.add(row,rowArray) = data;`)

Comment: wow, = data shouldnt be there,  completely missed that thanks